# How to rename file name in ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am copying data from sql to adls dynamically, i want to rename the file name after copied into ADLS. How to achieve it? Requesting you suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Ashok

Comment: What type of file is on the sink side? Is the file naming rule based on the table name?

Comment: @HarrisXu: Dynamically we are generating filenames based on source table name and storing it in ADLS parquet format

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be "why bother renaming parquet files?" Hopefully you aren't generating a single parquet file, which would seem to defeat the purpose of using Parquet. Instead, my focus would be on the folder name.

**OPTION 1**

If I did care about the file names, I would use Data Flow and configure the Sink to use patterned naming:

[image]

You could then pass the desired file name in as Data Flow Parameter:

[image]

And set it dynamically using an expression:

[image]

[**NOTE**: I haven't tested this syntax, but I recommend you always use the Expression Builder to enter these expressions].

**OPTION 2**

If none of that suits your purposes, then aonther option would be brute force. Use a COPY activity with binary data sets to copy the file to a new file with the desired name, then a DELETE activity to remove the old one.